# Why am I getting NaN values when I concat two panda dataframes>

Tags: python, pandas, merge

I have created 2 data frames. One called 'dfmas' with a set of closing prices and moving averages;

```
            PX_OPEN  PX_HIGH  PX_LOW  PX_LAST      ma5        ma8        ma21
Date                                                                         

12/19/2016   117.90   118.03  116.55   117.09  117.086  116.22625  114.231905
12/20/2016   117.09   118.24  116.99   117.86  117.620  116.70375  114.567143
12/21/2016   117.86   118.07  117.11   117.55  117.722  116.98250  114.872381
12/22/2016   117.55   117.88  117.27   117.54  117.594  117.29750  115.111429
```

I have then created another panda data frame 'ma5xdf' that shows me when the 5 day moving average is rising (+1) and falling (-1) or level (0);

```
    ma5x
0      0
1      0
2      0
3      0
4     -1
5     -1
6     -1
7     -1
8      1
9      1
```

I want to then merge the two dataframes into 1 but i'm getting a load of NaN values for the rising/falling 5 day , and also at the tail of the original 'dfmas' data. I'm using;

```
dfx = pd.concat([dfmas, ma5xdf], axis =1) 
print(dfx.tail(4))
```

and I get;

```
      PX_OPEN  PX_HIGH  PX_LOW  PX_LAST  ma5  ma8  ma21  ma5x
1845      NaN      NaN     NaN      NaN  NaN  NaN   NaN   1.0
1846      NaN      NaN     NaN      NaN  NaN  NaN   NaN   1.0
1847      NaN      NaN     NaN      NaN  NaN  NaN   NaN   1.0
1848      NaN      NaN     NaN      NaN  NaN  NaN   NaN   1.0
```

any help with the code would be gratefully accepted, thank you!

Comment: `pd.concat` is a merge on either the `index` (with `axis=0`, the default) or `columns` (with `axis=1`).  When you concat with another object whose index (or columns) don't align, it produces the outer join.  You need to make `ma5xdf` with an index from `dfmas`

Comment: What's your desired output for your input data? The 2 DFs seem to have different number of rows.

Comment: The desired output is to have ma5xdf aligned to dfmas. how the 5 day moving average rises or falls in relation to the actual 5 dma in dfmas. I'm not sure how to index it to dfmas, or how to align as df5xdf has 1 less row????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you simple want to add the column of your second dataframe(ma5xdf) at the ending of your first dataframe(dfmas) you can do this.

```
ma5xdf['ma5x'] = ma5xdf['ma5x'].astype(float)
dfmas['ma5x'] = ma5xdf['ma5x']
```

A simple and precise solution.

I see that your index is set for `date` column in dfmas.

so another approach.

```
dfmas.reset_index(drop=True,inplace=True)
ma5xdf['ma5x'] = ma5xdf['ma5x'].astype(float)
dfmas['ma5x'] = ma5xdf['ma5x']
dfmas = dfmas.set_index('Date')
```

Comment: It's now linking the panda data frames ok by using the first method thank you. But it wont accept 'Date' as an index?!? Also the dfmas floats are populating correctly but not the 'ma5x'.

Comment: @Bugsy try `ma5xdf['ma5x'].astype(float)` before you copy the column's of dataframe from ma5xdf to dfmax. your second query, that date could not be set an index, can you tell your column names, i guess 'Date' is not a column name, so it might be showing index error.  See edit.